# Why my css class does not load?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have `header.js` file like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Classes from '../css/style.css';

class Header extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <header>
                <div className={Classes.logo}>Logo</div>
            </header>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

the problem the class name `logo` is not loaded, after inspect this in the browser the html appear like this:

```
<div>Logo</div>
```

why is that ?

Comment: Are you using CSS Modules?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings yes. in the course I follow I modified web pack dev

Comment: What is the content of Classes.logo?

Comment: You should add the contents of the css file to your question, and console.log what Classes.logo is and add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen CSS classes used this way in React before. Does this this work?

```
return (
    <header>
        <div className="logo">Logo</div>
    </header>
)
```

This assumes you have a `.logo` class in your style.css and your bundler is configured to handle CSS.

Comment: I see now the style was embedded inside the html but why I can not use `{classes.logo}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `{Classes.logo}` would imply you have some stateful object named `Classes` with a `logo` property

All you have is imported a CSS file, which has no dynamic state, therefore you only need a string of the classes to load on this tag

```
className="logo"
```

Where the CSS has

```
.logo {}
```

Comment: I removed this line `import Classes from '../css/style.css';` and still the file is loaded !! how is that ?

Comment: I'm not able to answer that without seeing the rest of the project, but the short answer would be something else loaded the CSS

Comment: any idea where I should search ? the `index.html` does not load any css

Comment: The '../css/style.css' might have been imported using <style>. Please check index.html in your public folder for that

Comment: found it it as imported in another component which rendered in the same page. sorry guys I am new in react

Comment: but in the course the instructor used `{classes.logo}` and it work !! any ideas ?

Comment: You should always uses `classes.logo`, the second part of this answer is incorrect. This allows webpack to properly align class names if it mangles them to make them unique when compiling and still line up

Comment: @AndyRay `{classes.logo}` does not work !! do you know why ?